# closing open socket in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

Im wondering is there any way to find out the socket that is open and then to close it?

For instance,I have a script "SendInfo.py" which opens a socket and sends some info over TCP.

If I call this script to run it e.g. "python SendInfo.py" , it will open a new socket.

If I run this script again using "python SendInfo.py", which will send some more up to date information, I would like to cancel the previous TCP transaction and start a new one - e.g. by closing the previous socket.

How do I get access to the open socket at the beginning of my script in order to close it? Ive tried looking into threads, but Im similarly confused about which threads are open and how to close open threads etc.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.settimeout(2)
s.connect((self.__host, PORT))
```

Comment: is the previous script finished when you run it again?

Comment: No perhaps not, I'm guessing is there a way to terminate it and close the socket connection at the same time? Sorry a bit new to python

Comment: terminating it will close the socket. a typical http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: hmmmn im not sure how to terminate it though. Im using jython, so no clear way to terminate I dont think. Is there any way to terminate all running scripts?

Comment: Update/replace your question. Sockets are irrelevant.

Comment: Im looking for suggestions, youve suggested just one way. There are many ways to close sockets by threads etc. I'm trying to get an idea of the different ways - to find what is best in this scenario

Comment: The simplest method is to hard code the socket that you are using, then there will be no doubt as to the id of the socket and subsequent calls to the program will refuse to start until the currently running process is terminated.

Comment: Hi Rolf, Ive updated my question, because I believe I am hard coding the socket, but I'm not sure how to find it's id - any idea how to do that?

Comment: You cannot (directly) close a socket that resides in another process. You may be able to kill the other process, which would result in  its socket being closed by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after but here is a method of ensuring that the script is only running once and killing an existing running script.
You may find something useful in it. (This is for Linux)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# running.py
# execute by making the script executable
# put it somewhere on $PATH and execute via running.py 
# or execute via ./running.py
import os, sys, time , signal, socket
running_pid = os.popen('ps --no-headers -C running.py').read(5)
try:
    running_pid = int(running_pid)
except:
    running_pid = 0
current_pid = int(os.getpid())
if running_pid != 0:
    if running_pid != current_pid:
        print "Already running as process", running_pid
        print "Killing process", running_pid
        os.kill(int(running_pid), signal.SIGKILL)
#        sys.exit()
# Create a listening socket for external requests
tcp_port = 5005
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except:
    print "Error on Socket 5005"

# force re-use of the socket if it is in time-out mode after being closed
# other wise we can get bind errors after closing and attempting to start again
# within a minute or so
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

try:
    sock.settimeout(0.10)
    sock.bind(("localhost", tcp_port))
except IOError as msg:
    print "Error on Socket Bind "+str(tcp_port)+", running.py is probably already running"
    pass
try:
    sock.listen((1))
except:
    print "Error on Socket listen"

time.sleep(60)
sock.close()
```